Nested Cursors are bad, what other options do I have?
I have two sets of values:

a Bunch of trigger events (ex. status)
a Bunch of mail addresses

I have two given tables, which I am not allowed to change, lets call them 'triggers' and 'actions'.
They have a 1:n connection from triggers.number to actions.triggernumber.
Both tables have a PK 'number' which is not auto increment.
I now have to add a new row in triggers for each status I want the program to react on.
Seems easy first, but I had to increment the number also, because it have to be unique by table definition.
Then I have to add a row, for each mail address, to table 'actions' with 'triggernumber' must be the 'number' of the before added row to 'triggers' (ForeignKey relation)
For the first part I found the answer googling, to create a temp. table with the status, create a cursor on it an iterate through the results, fetch each row and make an insert statement to the table triggers.
Before I declare a variable 'LastNumber' and set the result of  'Select ISNull(MAX(Number),0)+1 from triggers' to it.
This variable I use then for the 'number' on my insert to the table 'triggers' And later I can use it for the 'triggernumber' in the table 'actions'
The easiest idea for me would now be to use a second cursor on a temp table for the mail addresses, iterate through them, fetch every mail and insert them in 'actions', also calculate an increment for the column 'number' and use the variable as 'triggernumber'
By checking if it is possible to nest cursors, because @@Fetch_Status is not explicit bound to one cursor I stumble about a answer to a similar question, that nested cursors are evil and there would nearly no case where it is necessary.
So my question is there a better way to achieve what I have to do?
That said, I will add my code, which I have so far.
Since for some reason I don't understand, the creator of the database, create everything with German names, it might be a little hard to understand.
Begin Transaction
Declare @Customernumber int
Declare @MailAddresses nvarchar(max)
Set @Customernumber = 13414
Set @MailAddresses = 'mail@example.de,mail2@otherexample.de'


Declare @NextLFDNREreignis int
Declare @Emails as Table (Mail nVarchar(320))
--### Fill temp Table with Mailaddresses 
Insert into @EMails (Mail) 
Select 
    i.value
From string_split(@MailAddresses,',') as i

Declare @Value1 varchar(50)
Declare @Value2 varchar(50)

Declare db_cursor cursor for Select UnterbearbeitungsStatus,Bezeichnung from BenachrichtigungsEreignisse Where Mandant = 1 And KundenNummer = 1 and Geschaeftsbereich = 'Service'
Open db_cursor

Fetch Next from db_cursor Into @Value1,@Value2 

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    Set @NextLFDNREreignis = (Select ISNull(MAX(LfdNrEreignis),0)+1 from BenachrichtigungsEreignisse WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK))

    --### Einfügen der Trigger ###
    Insert Into BenachrichtigungsEreignisse
        (Mandant
        ,LfdNrEreignis
        ,Bezeichnung
        ,Versandbedingung
        ,LfdNrGruppe
        ,KundenNummer
        ,AngelegtProgramm
        ,AngelegtDurch
        ,AngelegtAm)
    Values
        (1
        ,@NextLFDNREreignis
        ,@Value2
        ,9999
        ,1
        ,@Customernumber
        ,'Script'
        ,'MM'
        ,getdate()
        )

    --### Einfügen der Ereignisse ###
    Insert into BenachrichtigungsReaktionen 
        (Mandant
        ,LfdNrEreignis
        ,LfdNrReaktion
        ,ReaktionsArt
        ,EmpfaengerAdresse
        ,AngelegtProgramm
        ,AngelegtDurch
        ,AngelegtAm
        )
    Values
        (1
        ,@NextLFDNREreignis
        ,1 --Todo:increment number
        ,1 --send Mail
        ,'mail@example.de'
        ,'Script'
        ,'MM'
        ,getdate()
        )

    Fetch Next From db_cursor Into @Value1,@Value2
End
close db_cursor
deallocate db_cursor

commit

'BenachrichtigungsEreignisse' is the 'triggers' table
'BenachrichtigungsReaktionen' is the 'actions' table
EDIT!
Ok, next attempt :)
I have tried to create an example for you here
https://dbfiddle.uk/_VUVjCZH
I get the variables @CustomerNumber and @MailAddresses from user input.
Based on these variables I would like to generate for the customer '15000'
generate entries in TableA with one entry for each mail address from variable @MailAddresses in TableB.
Select * from TableA Where CustomerNumber = 0815
Serves as a template which entries I want to create for customer 1500.

It's not just nested cursors, it's generally cursors that are bad. Why are you using a CURSOR at all here? Why not parse your data as what it is: a dataset.

"Set @NextLFDNREreignis = (Select ISNull(MAX(LfdNrEreignis),0)+1 from BenachrichtigungsEreignisse WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK))" are you aware of the IDENTITY property, or SEQUENCEs?

Classic XY problem

Wait, are you saying that this code is run inside a trigger? Why the transaction declarations if so then? Triggers are already implicitly wrapped in a transaction, as they are part of a DML operation.

I don't think you need cursors, but it's also hard to understand what you're trying to do. Perhaps better just add the source tables and what you want to achieve when you're done with it.

MAX(Number)+1 is a very bad idea that guarantees duplicates. All that's needed is to delete some of the latest values, and the same numbers will be generated again.

@ThomA maybe because i don't know how. And Mainly i have no idea how to azomaticli increaye the triggers.number und post it over to the actions.triggernumber
If i understand IDENTETY correct, it woul alter my table, what im not allowed, or better wich i dont want, because it is not my program and i cant control if the table is still the same after an update.
SEQUENCE sounds intresting but i do not realy have an idea how to use it. Maybe yiou have an example for me?
No this runs manual, so not in a trigger.

The documentation, SEQUENCE, is a great place to start. SQL Server's documentation is full of examples. I'm afraid I'm struggling to understand some of the comment though; I don't know what you mean by "azomaticli", for example.

It's a lot better to explain what you actually want to do, not how you assume it should be done. Running this code in a trigger will generate the same rows over and over and over, because inserted isn't used anywhere. If you want an incrementing row number you can use the ROW_NUMBER function, eliminating the need for the cursor entirely. You can use a single SELECT to get all rows with individual numbers

@PanagiotisKanavos Yes i know, but since my script will be the only one wich will add or delete rows this is very unlikely

@Michael post the tables, sample data, expected output explain the problem. SQL is the same for everyone. this is very unlikely that means it will fail the 2nd time you run it. Your query reads the exact same rows every time. And that HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK suggests it already failed, so you tried to increase locking. SQL has no need for such tricks

Ok, i thougt i described what i want to achive in the first part of my question, but it seem that it wasn't good enoug, or maybe the language barier comes in the way

Well, you talk about triggers, a lot, in  your question, @Michael , but in your above comment you stated it's not in a trigger, so we already have conflicting information. The code, as Panagiotis mentions, doesn't reference the inserted (or deleted) object(s), which would be expected for a trigger too. The lack of use of IDENTITY or SEQUENCE, and  a CURSOR, makes it all looks like a massive XY Problem.

No, it's not a language barrier. You describe what you assume the solution is. There are no CREATE TABLE statements for all those tables, no INSERT INTO statements that insert sample data, no example output. Even let's call them triggers is causing confusion - a TRIGGER is a specific object type, created with CREATE TRIGGER.

Do we? Very near the beginning of the question, we have " have two given tables, witch (sic) i not allowd to change, lets call them 'triggers' and 'actions'.". One of the tables is called triggers (which, by all means, let's pillory them for their choice of table name).

So, really, what you need to do is take a step back; don't tell us what you have as, with all due respect, it's very wrong. Instead show us what your data looks like, ideally with DDL and DML statements, and then explain what you are trying to achieve and demonstrate your expected results.

Okay, I've confused you. Sorry.
'triggers' is the abstract name I would use in English for the first table, because the values in it are exactly that.
They are conditions that are checked by the application when data records (orders) are changed and if they are true, the second table is used to determine which actions to perform.

Ok, I understand, sorry about that.

Ok, I'll try to create sample tables and sample data for you.
I tried to create a create statement with SQL Managementstudio, but it is full of hundreds of constraints that are not relevant for the actual question.
Give me some time

Ok, I have revised my original question and tried to add the requested example tables and expected results.
Maybe that will make it clearer.

Why is trigger type not unique by status? eg 1,'disponierbar'
1,'geliefert' and in an English site such as this it would be more meaningful if the status was in english

@P.Salmon The TriggerType is only a reference to other columns in the orders to which the program should react. However, these are not important for the example.
For example, TriggerType 1 means that the program checks the status against the processing status, whereas TriggerType 2 checks against the sub-processing status.
As I said, this is actually irrelevant for the example.

And yes, the string could have been in English, but on the one hand atok couldn't think of a translation and on the other hand that is also completely irrelevant, in the end the program makes a string comparison and it could also say 'hfghjkö' and it would also work.

I suggest to do the following, create a temp table where you populate what you want to insert into the "triggers"-table.
For ID, you fetch max(id) the way you do it, and then just do update of the source table and then you're good to go.
Here's a skeleton implementation of how i'd do this:
create table #sources (newID INT, someData NVARCHAR(MAX))

insert into #sources (someData)
values( 'sometrigger'), ('someothertrigger'), ('someNthTrigger')

declare @id int

select @id = max(id)
from YourTriggerTable with (someLocks)

update t
set newID = newIDNew + @id
from (
    select *
    , row_number() over(order by (select null)) as newIDNew
    from #sources
    ) t

insert into YourTriggerTable (
    ID, someData)
select newID, someData
from #sources s

-- Now for emails...

Insert into YourTriggerAction (
    TriggerID, ActionID, Email
)
SELECT  newID, (SELECT MAX(ActionID) FROM YourTriggerAction WITH (SOMELOCKS)) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
,   em.value
FROM    #sources s
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT('mail@example.de,mail2@otherexample.de', ',') em


I must admit, I really think a SEQUENCE would be a much better choice here, if the OP can't ALTER the existing table.

I don't disagree, but the main idea is pretty much the same, only difference is how the max values is fetched

You wouldn't get the max for a sequence, you'd just get the NEXT VALUE FOR the SEQUENCE, which works for datasets as well as single rows: db<>fiddle

If this were a new design, SEQUENCE may be the best choice, but the OP is adding a process to an existing application (evidenced by "two given tables, which I am not allowed to change"). There may already be logic elsewhere in the application stack that inserts rows into these tables with its own ID assignment logic. If a sequence were implemented, that logic would also need to be changed. The main point of the above solution is that a range of ID values can be assigned in set operations (one for each target table), eliminating the need for any cursors.
